# If I work for a certain company through a contracting agency, how will that affect my background checks?

Tags: background-check, contractors

Basically as the title says. And should I put the contracting agency on my resume or just their client (the employer I'll be working with)?

Also, how will this affect my background checks? Will background checks return the contractor who in turn will return the client or just the contractor?

Comment: I am also asking about how it affects background checks. @DavidK

Comment: see also [What to write on a background check](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/67256/what-to-write-on-a-background-check)

Comment: thanks @DavidK should've assumed there would be those two separate questions somewhere

Comment: You should put whom ever pays you, and whom ever, signs your tax forms.  In other word your employer

Answer (score 2):

I think you should put the contracting agency on your resume because you don't know what kind of contract was signed between the companies , and the client might not want other people to know about it.

Answer (score 0):

You do it this way.....

Client Name(Contract)                                ... [start date] to [end date]

Remember, you the work you are doing is for the client, not the agency.